# ps3joy in Fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, ps3joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the title says it all, since it does not appear to be in the archive any longer, what's the best way to get the ps3joy.py node spun up in Fuerte?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32956/ps3joy-in-fuerte/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2012-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Install: # apt-get install ros-fuerte-joystick-drivers

Run: # rosrun ps3joy ps3joy.py

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2012-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0